# Should error reporting bind *print-circle* to T?

Tags: error-handling, common-lisp

When CL reports an error, it often prints objects which caused the error.

**Should CL bind [`*print-circle*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_cir.htm) (or [`*print-length*`/`*print-level*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_lev.htm)) when printing errors?**

The [ANSI CL Standard](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/09_ac.htm) seems to be silent on the issue.

- **Pro**:  Stack overflow errors like [Clisp "Program stack overflow. RESET" on a (cadr). How?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41796893/850781) are avoided.
- **Con**: ordinary error messages can become

  - too cluttered and, thus, less comprehensible to novice users (this is why `*print-circle*` defaults to `nil`) or
  - too brief and, thus, less comprehensible (this is why `*print-level*` and `*print-length*` default to `nil`)

This seems to be an example of a ["Low-Probability High-Consequence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_risk) situation: circular structures are relatively rare, but inability to print them in error messages is devastating to an unsuspecting user.

SBCL seems to do that (in fact, it prints the offending object *twice*, once with [`*print-length*`/`*print-level*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_lev.htm) and once with `*print-circle*`).

CLISP does not.

Comment: Most CL implementations have their own variables that specify the values that will be used for the `*PRINT-XXX*` variables in the debugger.

Comment: @barmar: sure, but the same question remains wrt the default values of those debugger variables. IOW, you are talking about an implementation detail.

Comment: The debugger variables are typically set to "safe" values, so that you don't get infinite recursion in the debugger.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Why are you asking if it *should* bind the variables? Either it does or it doesn't. Or are you writing your own CL implementation, and asking for advice on its design?

Comment: Your second comment is the answer I was looking for: it's okay to bind the printer variables in debugger. Thanks. I will do that in CLISP.

Comment: @Barmar **"Why are you asking if it should bind the variables? Either it does or it doesn't."** Sure, but the spec were to actually prescribe one behavior or the other, then an implementation that does something different can at least be identified as non-conforming, and the behavior reported as a (possible) bug.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: in this case, the spec does not go deep into aspects of the runtime or development environment anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's left to the implementation and or the development environment.

Note that we are talking about printing errors, not the value of `*print-circle*` in a debugger.

Clozure CL for example has the variable `*ERROR-PRINT-CIRCLE*`, which provides the corresponding value for `*print-circle*` when printing errors.

Similar CCL has values for `*error-print-level*` and `*error-print-length*`.

Comment: `(define-condition test (error) () (:report (lambda (e s) (format s "PRINT CIRCLE: ~A" *print-circle*))))`, then, under SBCL, `(error 'test)` prints `PRINT-CIRCLE: T`, even though the variable is globally set to NIL. That definitely could be confusing.

Comment: @coredump: you probably see an effect of SLIME. Try it on a console, too.